# Zend Lucene - Wildcard search based off of Fuzzy search

Tags: php, zend-framework, search, lucene, zend-lucene

Goal: execute fuzzy search, then wildcard search with those similar terms

I have a boolean query in place at the moment, shown below:

```
$query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Boolean();

$pattern = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term("*$string*");
$subquery1 = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Wildcard($pattern);

$term = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term("$string");
$subquery2 = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Fuzzy($term);

$query->addSubquery($subquery1, null  /* optional */);
$query->addSubquery($subquery2, null  /* optional */);

$hits = $index->find($query);
```

This seems to be executing an either/or search. For example: if I search for the term

```
"berry"
```

I hit everything with "berry" anywhere in the title

```
berry, wild berry, strawberry, blueberry
```

But if I search for

```
"bery"
```

I only hit results like

```
berry
```

I'm not exactly sure how the fuzzy search is powered. Is there a way to modify my query so that I can wildcard search after the fuzzy search returns the similar terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that field is not analyzed when indexed.

So, with the first query, you are getting hits from the wildcard query.  `*berry*` matches all of the examples you've given.  `*bery*` doesn't match any of the documents, though, since it's not actually a substring of any of them.

For the fuzzy query, terms are compared by edit distance ([Damerau–Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance)).  An edit distance of two is the default maximum for a match.

- `bery` to `berry` - edit distance: 1
- `bery` to `wild berry` - edit distance: 6
- `bery` to `strawberry` - edit distance: 6
- `bery` to `blueberry` - edit distance: 5

This could be handled in part by using an analyzer, instead of indexing the entire string as a single token.  Standard analyzer would split `wild berry` up into the tokens `wild` and `berry`, and you could expect a fuzzy match on that.

As far as strawberry and blueberry, unless your analyzer splits apart `straw` and `berry` somehow, you could manually specify terms to split apart by incorporating a [`SynonymFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter.html) into your analyzer.

Another option would be to attempt to correct the query spelling before searching, using lucene's [`SpellChecker`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/SpellChecker.html)